# Splitting dataframe into multiple dataframes by using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question related to splitting dataframes into multiple dataframes using groupby such that on each iteration i cover more than one grouped by item. I looked at the forum n found the below example to be very close to my problem. However, i was wondering if there is any possibility of printing all the rows of more than one grouped by item per iteration in the loop. So from below example, in my 1st iteration, is it possible to print all the rows of Region A, B, C and then iterate again for next 3 regions?

```
for region, df_region in df.groupby('Region'):
    print(df_region)

  Competitor Region ProductA ProductB
0      Comp1      A      £10      £15
3      Comp2      A       £9      £16
6      Comp3      A      £11      £16

  Competitor Region ProductA ProductB
1      Comp1      B      £11      £16
4      Comp2      B      £12      £14
7      Comp3      B      £10      £15

  Competitor Region ProductA ProductB
2      Comp1      C      £11      £15
5      Comp2      C      £14      £17
8      Comp3      C      £12      £15
```

I am learning and implementing python/ pandas so still a beginner of this language. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please specify the expected output so that we can help you.

Comment: Hi Jonas, in the above output, there are 3 iterations to fetch the rows of region A, B & C. I am looking for a way to extract all the rows of regions A,B, C in a single loop. The reason to post this question is that my data set with unique items can be around 780 and running the loop for 780 times could be time consuming (my suspicion). Hence to limit the number of iteration, i want to take few grouped items and fetch their results, lets say 10 thus reducing the number of iterations to 78. Hope this helps you to suggest a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical terminology for this is batching: you're returning values from your dataframe in batches of some size in order to avoid getting everything at once (batch of size equal to the length of your dataframe) or one item at a time (batch size equal to 1). As you said, under certain conditions this can improve performance. Here's one way you might go about this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Region": ["A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F"],
                       "Product A": [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]})
```

Don't use those lines above, this is just so that I can replicate your dataframe. Here's the approach, feel free to change batch_size as you wish:

```
batch_size = 3
regions = df["Region"].unique()
b = 0
while True:
  r = regions[b*batch_size:(b+1)*batch_size]
  if len(r) == 0:
    break # already went through all the regions
  else:
    b += 1 # increment so that the next iterations gets the next set of regions
  print(f"batch: {b}")
  sub_df = df.loc[df["Region"].isin(r)]
  print(sub_df)
```

`sub_df` will be the batched results, with the values for only `batch_size` number of regions each iteration.

Comment: Wonderful Jonas. This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for your help and providing an optimal solution.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if it solved your problem :)